# Conditional JOIN based on column value

Tags: mysql, sql, join, aggregates

I've looked all over, and unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm developing a personal financial management application that uses a MySQL server. For this problem, I have 4 tables I'm working with.

The `TRANSACTIONS` table contains columns `CATID` and `BILLID` which refer to primary keys in the `SECONDARYCATEGORIES` and `BILLS` tables. Both the `TRANSACTIONS` and `BILLS` tables have a column `PCATID` which refers to a primary key in the `PRIMARYCATEGORIES` table.

I'm building a SQL query that sums an "amount" column in the `TRANSACTIONS` table and returns the primary key from `PCATID` and the sum from all records that are associated with that value. If the `BILLID` is set to `-1`, it should find the `PCATID` in `SECONDARYCATEGORIES` where `SECONDARYCATEGORIES.ID = TRANSACTIONS.CATID`, otherwise (since `-1` indicates this is NOT a bill), it should find the `PCATID` from the `BILL` record where `BILLS.ID` matches `TRANSACTIONS.BILLID`.

I'm looking for something like this (not valid SQL, obviously):

```
SELECT
 SECONDARYCATEGORIES.PCATID,
 SUM(TRANSACTIONS.AMOUNT)
FROM
 TRANSACTIONS
IF (BILLID = -1) JOIN SECONDARYCATEGORIES ON SECONDARYCATEGORIES.ID = TRANSACTIONS.CATID
ELSE JOIN SECONDARYCATEGORIES ON SECONDARYCATEGORIES.ID = BILLS.CATID WHERE BILLS.ID = TRANSACTIONS.BILLID
```

I have tried a myriad of different JOINs, IF statements, etc, and I just can't seem to make this work. I had thought of breaking this up into different SQL queries based on the value of `BILLID`, and summing the values, but I'd really like to do this all in one SQL query if possible.

I know I'm missing something obvious here; any help is very much appreciated.

Edit: I forgot to describe the BILLS table. It contains a primary category, ID, as well as some descriptive data.

Comment: two left outer joins should be able to solve your issue here. however your BILLS table is missing

Comment: I don't see BILLS table here.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `OR` in your `JOIN`, like this:

```
SELECT S.PCATID,
       SUM(T.AMOUNT)
FROM TRANSACTIONS T 
LEFT JOIN BILLS ON BILLS.ID = T.BILLID 
JOIN SECONDARYCATEGORIES S ON (S.ID = T.CATID AND T.BILLID = -1)
                           OR (S.ID = BILLS.CATID AND BILLS.ID = T.BILLID)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Somehow I was under the impression the AND/OR wasn't allowed in the ON portion of a JOIN. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: What is the performance impact of such conditional Joins? Is there any alternative way of not doing all the decision making in JOIN conditions?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `COALESCE` and `CASE` in your `JOIN`s.

```
SELECT ID = COALESCE(s.PCATID,b.PCATID)
    ,Total = SUM(t.AMOUNT)
FROM TRANSACTIONS t
LEFT JOIN BILLS b ON b.BILLID = CASE WHEN t.BILLID <> -1 THEN t.BILLID END
LEFT JOIN SECONDARYCATEGORIES s ON s.CATID = CASE WHEN t.BILLID = -1 THEN t.CATID END
GROUP BY COALESCE(s.PCATID,b.BILLID)
```

Comment: That's not a conditional join. That's doing the joins unconditionally and then picking one value or the other. That's not efficient.

Comment: @QuolonelQuestions actually, if you compare the execution plan generated by my query and the one generated by the accepted answer's query, you will find that they are nearly identical, save for a couple extra `Compute Scalar`s in my plan. My solution is no more inefficient than including an `OR` in a join clause.

Answer (score 0):

I use `UNION` to pick either query.  But the second query obviously won't work because it's missing `BILLS` table.

```
SELECT SECONDARYCATEGORIES.PCATID
    , SUM(TRANSACTIONS.AMOUNT)
FROM TRANSACTIONS
JOIN SECONDARYCATEGORIES ON SECONDARYCATEGORIES.ID = TRANSACTIONS.CATID AND BILLID = -1
UNION
SELECT SECONDARYCATEGORIES.PCATID
    , SUM(TRANSACTIONS.AMOUNT)
FROM TRANSACTIONS
JOIN SECONDARYCATEGORIES ON SECONDARYCATEGORIES.ID = BILLS.CATID AND BILLID <> -1
WHERE BILLS.ID = TRANSACTIONS.BILLID
```